# How to configure apache openCMIS bridge as an intermediate interceptor between the client and alfresco repository?

Tags: java, cmis, bridge, opencmis, apache-chemistry

Greetings to the community, I recently learned about the apache openCMIS bridge  and I found very interesting the capabilities that might give you. More specifically I found this answer [What is OpenCMIS Bridge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780256/what-is-opencmis-bridge) explaining what exactly it is. Unfortunately, apart from the [code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-bridge/chemistry-opencmis-bridge/src/main/java/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/bridge/AbstractBridgeServiceFactory.java) I did not find any useful information (resources/how-to/configuration setup) on the web.

What I would like to do is set it up on a server as an intermediate interceptor between the client and the actual server where my alfresco repository is hosted. From the description I understand that it fits my case.

Currently I have downloaded the openCMIS bridge .war file from here 
https://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html and I have deployed it on a tomcat Server. I would like to "somehow" configure my servers to work as described above

(client sends request --> openCMIS bridge server intercepts the request --> openCMIS bridge server sends the request to the server ).

Any resources / instructions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have figured how CMIS Bridge works by now.

But still will go on to answer the question for the community.

Essentially CMIS bridge is both a server and client.

You have to implement the bridge as CMIS  Server Service and connect to a backend session as a CMIS Client.

I have submitted one sample CMIS bridge implementation which connects to CMIS File Share repository.

Code is here https://github.com/saurav28/DemoCmisBridge

Best Regards,
Saurav